# query file write status via batch (CMD client to BASH server)

Tags: bash, batch-file, cmd

**Short story: need a method to get the write-status of a file on a server (using BASH) from a client (using CMD batch).**

Long-time lurker, first-time poster. I did many searches on variations of what I'm looking for and have not yet found enough data.

I am writing a batch file in CMD (because the clients could be any WinOS [XP - up] with unknown packages installed). The batch uses puTTY's "plink" to connect via SSH to the server. Once connected to the server, plink executes a command to write data to a new file.
Once that file is written, I use PSCP to copy the file to the client
*So far, so good; I have successfully accomplished all of this.*

The creation of that file is instantaneous but the time it takes to write all of the data is unknown / variable. Therefore I need an automated method to determine when the file is complete, to then copy it. Simply using timeout/sleep for XX seconds is not feasible in my circumstances.

The approach I have taken so far (as of yet unsuccessfully) is to repeatedly grab the filesize using "stat -c '%s' filemane" and run that in a loop until grab1 EQU grab2, indicating a complete file. I am finding this difficult because I can't get the output of stat into the CMD batch to process it.

Q1: Is this (stat result going into CMD for loop) the best approach? Maybe there's something existing in BASH?

Q2: if Q1 is true, any ideas on how to get the stat result into the CMD batch as a variable to parse/analyze the data?

Thanks in advance for suggestions and your time.
DCT

Comment: Why can't you just for the command writing the file to complete before PLINK exits?

Comment: I have no control over the program creating/writing to the file. Once I issue the "make a file" command, it responds back with a success message, however the file(s) are not necessarily completed then. If the success message were "connected" to the file completion, I would not have to work around this.

Comment: "I am finding this difficult because I can't get the output of stat into the CMD batch to process it." I would suggest using WSH/VBScript rather than CMD for something like this, because of the difficulties you describe with getting the output from a command into CMD.EXE to process.

Comment: I was able to get the output of stat into cmd by saving the stat string as a local file, then pulling that file into a variable in the batch. I am still working on the logic of comparing file a and file b...slow, but making headway.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have the command writing the file write it with a temp filename. So if it will be called `xyz.txt`, have it written with filename `tmpxyz.txt.tmp`, then the final step will be a rename.

That way you can just check for the presence of the named file.

Usually a good idea to give the file a unique name, probably incorporating the date and time, I find.

Comment: Thanks for replying Ben. I need to determine when the file is finished being written to. If the program has not completed writing to the file it does me no good to transfer it.